# understanding the difference between CGPostKeyboardEvent and CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to send a keystroke to the focused application, and my first searches led me to [CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html):

```
CGEventRef eventA = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)0, true);
CFRelease(eventA);
```

This compiled but didn't do anything, but in the process of trying to figure it out I found this...

```
CGPostKeyboardEvent( (CGCharCode)'a', (CGKeyCode)0, true);
```

...and it worked. Why? From what I've read so far about this, they should be accomplishing the same thing, but [CGPostKeyboardEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPostKeyboardEvent) is deprecated.

(Forgive me if I'm ignoring details that I should obviously include -- I'm working way out my usual depth, trying to help colleagues with an extracurricular project, and just trying to learn a few things along the way.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not posting the event once you've created it. So the following code will press the left arrow and then release it:

```
CGEventRef a = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 123, true);
CGEventRef b = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 123, false);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, a);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, b);
```

Comment: Aha! This project is long since over, but it's nice to hear a correct-sounding answer. I don't know if I'll have a chance to verify this but I strongly suspect you're correct so I'll mark this as accepted; thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. I was looking at a similar issue and a google search turned up your question. I got it working, so I figured I should post it here as well.